# Dealing with decimals in C

Tags: c, linux, floating-point

I am writing an application in C (under Linux) which deals with prices. The program receives price quotes in a form of integer pairs (m, e) so that the resulting price is simply 'm * 10^e'.

I'd like to be able both manipulate the prices with arithmetical operations and use "*printf*"-like functions for formatting output. I have to do that pretty fast.

What is the fastest way dealing decimals in C? I've read about [Decimal Floats in gcc](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Decimal-Float.html#Decimal-Float), but their lack of libc support makes them impossible to use in a standard way. Thank you.

Comment: What does "pretty fast" mean? This is presumably on a multi-gigahertz CPU, how many operations on such prices do you have to deal with per second? If it isn't in the millions, you should probably not worry about performance right now.

Comment: I'm afraid, you'll have to implement your own set of functions for the arithmetic operations on such numbers and for printing.

Comment: To be more concrete, I will be fine if I can deal with them in a "double"-type speeds. If it is possible to do in an elegant way, it will be great.

Comment: Floating point ALUs were invented exactly for the purpose of doing what you need (addition, multiplication, etc) fast in hardware. Doing this manually in software will make it some 10 times slower at the very least. Elegance is the least problem here, IMO.

Comment: I'm afraid I didn't catch your point. Could you please elaborate a bit on what you are suggesting to do? Thank you.

Comment: What are the minimum and maximum values for `m` and for `e`, not just in the input and output but in all the calculations you intend to perform? As stated in your question, the only limit on them is that they are integers, but integers can be any size, so you are asking for arbitrary-precision arithmetic. If `m` and `e` are sufficiently limited, you can perform arithmetic using operations built into the processor. If `m` and `e` are larger, various other options might be explained to you. But you must state the problem precisely in order to get a good answer.

Comment: Also, what operations do you need to perform, and will `e` fall within a smaller range in any one set of calculations? For example, do you just need to add and subtract values and multiply by simple percentages, or do you need to calculate exponentials and arbitrary fractions? Will you ever need to combine values where `e` is 0 with values where `e` is 10, or will `e` be some value, such as 3, for a particular set of data and remain 3 (or near it) throughout the work with that data?

Comment: The point is that you're inevitably going to reinvent floating-point arithmetic in software and write fairly large routines for things that the CPU does as a single floating-point instruction (e.g. `FADD`, `FMUL`, etc). The only difference is that the CPU does it for binary and you need it for a mixed binary-decimal representation. See if `GMP` can help. Writing all the necessary code from scratch without using external libraries is possible too.

Answer (score 1):

You can of course use a library such as [GMP](http://gmplib.org/), it supports arbitrary floating-point precision so it should be able to deal with your data.

Answer (score 1):

If your prices are always at the most to 2 decimal places then you can just use integers to represent the number of cents. printf is also simple with

```
printf("%d.%02d", price/100, price%100 );
```